# Image View in Button Doesn't Appear

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to use the background view of the image view of a `UIButton` but for some reason it will not show up. This is what I have tried:

```
detailCell.greenPriorityButton.imageView.frame = detailCell.greenPriorityButton.frame;
[detailCell.greenPriorityButton.imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[detailCell.greenPriorityButton.imageView setHidden:NO];
[detailCell.greenPriorityButton.imageView setOpaque:YES];
```

I have called `NSLog` on the `imageView` property and it seems everything is as it should be. I can also tap on the button and the method associated with it will be called so I know it exists. Just in case I am missing something here is the `NSLog` return:

```
<UIImageView: 0x1d97e1b0; frame = (254 61; 20 20); clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d97e210>>
```

The reason I am not using dot notation to set the image view properties above is because they don't seem to change the values. For example, if I say `detailCell.greenPriorityButton.imageView.hidden = NO;` it doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit**

The reason for not just setting the background color of the button and not its image view is because I am trying to create a small shape in the button. However I want the tappable space to have margins around the shape so it is still user friendly. I thought the image view property would lend useful as I could manipulate the frame and layer of that separately from the frame and layer of the button.

I have now tried adding a `UIView *greenBackground` as a subview to the button, however this doesn't appear either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a view that you can have within the view of the button for the purpose of setting its color then I would think that trying to use the imageview is the wrong approach. You could just add a subview that has the changed background color. something like this:

```
UIView *colorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];//Whatever rect you want that will be in reference to the frame of the button
colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[detailCell.greenPriorityButton addSubview:colorView];
```

Comment: I don't actually want to give it an image though. I just want to use the `backgroundColor` property of the `imageView` property.

Comment: Is the button a Custom Type button?

Comment: I did not subclass `UIButton` if that is what you mean. I added the button to the view via storyboard and connected via an `IBOutlet`. However, the view it is in is a subclassed `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: No I mean the type of the button being custom as opposed to "rounded rect". I'm sorry for not understanding your question fully first. If you are trying to just simply make the background of that button green you should change the type to custom and make it green but its image view.

Comment: Yes, it is a custom button as opposed to a "rounded rect." Please see my edited original question for further explanation of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Unfortunately, it doesn't show up. I have even tried making a test project with just a button and adding the subview but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well I just used the code I copied to you and it worked for me so I would check your outlets or maybe there is something else you may have missed.

Comment: I got it to work finally. For some reason it didn't like that I was setting the frame of the `colorView` in your example with `detailCell.greenPriorityButton.frame` and not `CGRectMake`. Anyways, thanks for all the help.